# Search and highlight text in PDF rendered in UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have used [brow-leaves-67b10ed](https://nodeload.github.com/brow/leaves/zipball/master) to render PDFs in UIView.

Now my necessity is to search and highlight texts.

I have managed to get the exact position of text on UIView. Now UIView consists of many layers to support leaves animation and also pages are cached in images and then drawn on these layers. Here the actual problem occurs. I want to draw a filled rectangle at searched position on top of all layers which I am unable to do. If I call setsneedRect for UIView, drawRect is called but rectangle is not drawn, and setsneedsRect for CALayer doesnt call drawLayer: inContext.. Can any one help me how to proceed?? Please reply asap.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Now the code is calling drawLayer: inContext:
I added below line..

```
[super setNeedsDisplay];
[searchLayer setNeedsDisplay];
```

But still nothing seems to happen..

Since I called setNeedsDisplay for CALayer (searchLayer) the context will be of CALayer.. 
Here is my code where I am displaying the highlights:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{
for (Selection *s in self.selections)
{
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, [s transform]);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, [s frame]);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}

}
```

Can any one help out there?

Comment: How are you getting the starting position of text in pdf page?

Comment: @Eimantas I am getting those with other files.. Lots are there.. But, if I am using those without leaves, I am getting exact positions.

Comment: This might help:

[Answer to similar question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737305/how-to-search-text-in-pdf-document-with-quartz/4738888#4738888

Comment: can you send the code for getting exact position of the searched text. then i will be help you in draw rect on text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was an issue with filling rect in inappropriate layer in leaves view. I tried adding those with proper layer position and that is done.

But I recommend, not to use UIView if you want to highlight searched text.. Not atleast leaves view